# Django filtering by two categories logic

Tags: python, django

```
def post_list(request):

    school_slug = request.GET.get('school', None)
    category_slug = request.GET.get('category', None)

    if VideoPost.objects.filter(approve = 1).exists():

        posts = VideoPost.objects.all().filter(approve = 1)

        if school_slug:
            posts = posts.filter(school=school_slug)

        if category_slug:
            posts = posts.filter(category=category_slug)

        posts = posts.order_by('-date_posted')

        return render(request, 'stories/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
    return render(request, 'stories/no_post.html')
```

I'm filtering the posts by getting URL parameter which would be

1) `example.com/post/` to display all posts

2) `example.com/post/?category=something` to display all posts with `something` category

3) `example.com/post/?category=something&school=someschool` to display with two filters

4) No post.html page when no post under the category.

The first three filtering works fine, but how should I filter to display no_post.html page ?
I tried to filter at exists(), then it would display no_post.html properly, but wouldn't display 1) properly.

How would I be able to make all 4 options work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check up if the post exist behind all filters

```
def post_list(request):

    school_slug = request.GET.get('school', None)
    category_slug = request.GET.get('category', None)

    posts = VideoPost.objects.all().filter(approve = 1)

    if school_slug:
        posts = posts.filter(school=school_slug)

    if category_slug:
        posts = posts.filter(category=category_slug)

    posts = posts.order_by('-date_posted')

    if not posts:
        return render(request, 'stories/no_post.html')

    return render(request, 'stories/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```